# Notify me when there is an update on the upstream of a repository I have forked

Tags: events, github, triggers, notifications

Say I have forked a repository to my github account.

1. Is it possible to trigger a notification if there are changes on the
   original repository [the upstream].
2. Is it possible to trigger a webhook for that event.

**Edit:**

It seems that my question is not very clear.
We have been using webhooks, but these are on the repos we own and maintain. So every-time there is a push or a commit etc. We all get notified.

My question was and is, Is it possible to do so for the forked repositories that we do not own. We would want an event to be triggered when a change is made on the parent repository [something we do not control].

The reason for forking the repository even when we may not added/edit to it, is to have control over the version of the code while deploying to the overall project to avoid regression issues when directly cloning from the parent repository, when or if changes are made [we have scheduled auto updates for our plugins].

This process gives code control but it also takes a lot of time to manually sync these repos without which we lose the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, there are webhooks found here.

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Specifically `PushEvent`:

https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pushevent

Comment: hi gotnull. I came across those as well. My question is how do you trigger them from my git account, or I just add it to that forked repo and it will just work? From what I can read from on GitHub webhook settings page is "Webhooks allow external services to be notified when certain events happen within your repository".

Comment: Suggest you read up on how to Create them https://developer.github.com/webhooks/creating/

Comment: @Kaushtuv Were you able to setup a webhook on your fork to "listen" to events (specifically merges to its main and develop branches) from the upstream repository?